# OMA Lightweight M2M Protocol

Tags: protocols

I just stumbled across the OMA Lightweight M2M Protocol (OMA LWM2M)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=22&v=g-41ZdcTnXc

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMA_LWM2M

https://github.com/OpenMobileAlliance/OMA_LwM2M_for_Developers

Would this protocol be suited for building a general purpose IoT infrastructure, including for instance both industrial and consumer IoT? 
Generally speaking, how it relates to other protocols? What are pros and cons and how much it's effectively used in the field?

Comment: This is not a question... But the answer is yes.